# How to use back button with React Router

Tags: reactjs, browser-history, react-router

I am having problem with ReactRouter.

Here how I init and run the router:

```
var routes = (
  <Route handler={App}>
    <DefaultRoute handler={Domains}/>
    <Route path="login" name="login" handler={Login}/>
    <Route path="signup" name="signup" handler={SignUp}/>
  </Route>);

var config = {routes, location: Router.HistoryLocation};
const router = Router.create(config);
export default router;

$(document).ready(() => {
  router.run( (Root) => {
    React.render(<Root/>, document.getElementById('maincontent'));
  });
});
```

Reading the docs, this way I expect that I when press the Back button of the browser, or use the goBack() method the browser go to the previous page.

Instead, when I use `goBack()` method, first remove an hash from the url (that the method transitionTo added), and only after call it again, it works. The same for the button.

Answer (score 0):

Per the docs, if you want to use `HistoryLocation` you have to configure your server to handle it..

[React Router Documentation - HistoryLocation](http://rackt.github.io/react-router/#HistoryLocation)

(a nodejs example):

```
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index');
});
```

Otherwise, you'll need to use HashLocation as that will keep it on the same page.

If that is set correctly, you can debug what's going on in the router by receiving the 2nd prop in `router.run` -- `state`.

[Here's the properties state contains.](http://rackt.github.io/react-router/#Router.run)

```
Router.run(routes, function(Handler, state) {
    console.log(state);
    React.render(<Handler>);
});
```

Comment: thanks, but my server is configured correctly. Do you know how can I debug the history of my router? I am narrowing down the problem to only special circumstances, but I need to see how the urls are stored

Comment: There's a second prop passed back in the `router.run` called `routeState` -- it is pretty much the context of the route results. You can log that to your console to inspect what is actually getting returned.